# object has no attribute 'META' when filtering Query in Django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

It's my first time encountered this problem, the error says

```
'TevList' object has no attribute 'META'
```

**I tried putting `.first()` after filter but the error retains**

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def tevemployee(request):
    tev_id = request.POST.get('tev_id')
    qs_list = TevList.objects.filter(id=tev_id).first()
    return JsonResponse({'data': list(qs_list)})
```

**ajax**

```
$('.item-details').click(function (event) {
let id = $(this).attr("id");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{% url 'tev-employee' %}",
    data:{
        tev_id : id
    }
    }).done(function(data){

  });
```

**models.py**

```
class TevList(models.Model):
employee_name = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=True, null=True)
original_amount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
status = models.CharField(default="On-going",max_length=128,blank=True, null=True)
incoming_remarks = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
correctness_remarks = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
date_in = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True, null=True)
date_out = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
user_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'tev_list'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your tevemployee view function in views.py. When you're trying to convert the qs_list object to a list using list(qs_list), it causes the error because qs_list is a single instance of the TevList model, not a list or iterable.

Serialize the object into JSON and use a dictionnary instead:

```py
from django.core import serializers

@csrf_exempt
def tevemployee(request):
    tev_id = request.POST.get('tev_id')
    qs_list = TevList.objects.filter(id=tev_id).first()

    # Check if the record exists
    if qs_list:
        # Serialize the object into JSON
        data = serializers.serialize('json', [qs_list])
        # Convert the serialized data to a dictionary
        data_dict = json.loads(data)[0]['fields']
        return JsonResponse({'data': data_dict})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Record not found'})
```